# Twice Integration Problem

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I came across the follwing problem in a paper that i am reading right now, 
$$
0 = \partial_x\bigg[-\frac{\sigma}{\sigma + 1}\partial_{xx}h + \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\Phi^{'}\bigg(\frac{h}{\varepsilon}\bigg)\bigg]
$$
with condtions:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} h = h_{\infty} \hspace{1cm} \lim_{x \to \infty} \partial_x h = 0 \hspace{1cm} \lim_{x \to \infty} \partial_{xx}h = 0
$$
where,
$$
\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\Phi^{'}\bigg(\frac{h}{\varepsilon}\bigg) = \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\bigg[\bigg(\frac{\varepsilon}{h}\bigg)^{3} - \bigg(\frac{\varepsilon}{h}\bigg)^{9}\bigg]
$$
It says, integrating the above equation twice gives:
$$
\partial_xh = \sqrt{2\frac{\sigma + 1}{\sigma}}\sqrt{\Phi\bigg(\frac{h}{\varepsilon}\bigg) - \Phi\bigg(\frac{h_\infty}{\varepsilon}\bigg) - \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\Phi^{'}\bigg(\frac{h_\infty}{\varepsilon}\bigg)(h - h_\infty)}
$$
This is what i have done so far. Integrating it just once and using the given conditions gives:
$$
0 = \frac{\sigma}{\sigma+1}\frac{\partial^{2}h}{\partial x^{2}} - \Phi^{'}\bigg(\frac{h}{\varepsilon}\bigg) + \Phi^{'}\bigg(\frac{h_{\infty}}{\varepsilon}\bigg)
$$
Integrating it again gives:
$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} = \frac{\sigma + 1}{\sigma} \int\bigg[\Phi^{'}\bigg(\frac{h}{\varepsilon}\bigg) - \Phi^{'}\bigg(\frac{h_{\infty}}{\varepsilon}\bigg)\bigg]\partial x
$$
I am not sure how to move ahead from this point to get the same result as in the paper.

Answer (score 0):

$$
-\frac{\sigma}{\sigma+1}\partial_{xx}h + \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\Phi'\left(\frac{h}{\varepsilon}\right) = \alpha
$$
first integration.

lets change of variable $v = h/\varepsilon$
we find
$$
-\varepsilon\frac{\sigma}{\sigma+1}\partial_{xx}v + \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\frac{d}{dv}\Phi\left(v\right) = \alpha
$$
lets utilize $v_xx = v_x\partial_v v_x = \frac{1}{2}\partial_v v_x^2$
we find
$$
-\varepsilon\frac{\sigma}{\sigma+1}\frac{1}{2}\partial_v v_x^2 + \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\frac{d}{dv}\Phi\left(v\right) = \alpha
$$
or
$$
\partial_v v_x^2 -\frac{2}{\varepsilon^2}\frac{\sigma + 1}{\sigma}\frac{d}{dv}\Phi\left(v\right) = -\frac{2}{\varepsilon}\frac{\sigma + 1}{\sigma}
$$
integrating again we find
$$
v_x^2 -\frac{2}{\varepsilon^2}\frac{\sigma + 1}{\sigma}\Phi(v) =  -\frac{2}{\varepsilon}\frac{\sigma + 1}{\sigma}v +C
$$
or 
$$
v_x = \sqrt{\frac{2(\sigma + 1)}{\sigma}}\sqrt{ \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}\Phi(v) - \frac{1}{\varepsilon}v + C_1} = \sqrt{\frac{2(\sigma + 1)}{\sigma}}\sqrt{ \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}\Phi\left(\frac{h}{\varepsilon}\right) - \frac{h}{\varepsilon^2} + C_1} 
$$
or finally
$$
h_x = \sqrt{\frac{2(\sigma + 1)}{\sigma}}\sqrt{\Phi\left(\frac{h}{\varepsilon}\right) - h + C_1\varepsilon^2} 
$$
then you can tidy up the constants.